# How to implement Multistate CheckBox in WPF for MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, checkbox

I have a requirement for which i need a **MultiState Checkboxes** in WPF...

Also as i am using MVVM so handling binding and Commands should follow the same as i will use it in my Views.

I have seen a Multistate checkbox in DotnetNuke(made in ASP.NET) but how to make it in WPF

some inputs in this regards will be helpful

Some example will be great...

Comment: There is no tag for Multistate Checkboxes in the site... o_O

Comment: So...which part are you struggling with?

Comment: I have to show change the Icon for 4 diferent states Agree,Disagree,Maybe,I Dont care.....

Comment: So....are you actually looking for Radio Buttons?

Comment: No a single checkBox will have Four states.... Clicking on it will toggle the four states : Agree,Disagree,Maybe,I dont know ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes have specific functionality (checked, unchecked, and optionally indeterminate).

Based on your comment, I would think it would be easiest to just do it as a button.  I don't have time now to test out an actual example, but here some pseudocode to get you going:

**XAML**

```
<Button Command="{Binding ToggleDecisionState}">
    <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="{Binding CurrentDecisionIcon}" />
    <Button.Content>
</Button>
```

**ViewModel (leaving out MVVM implementation details)**

```
enum Decisions
{
    Agree,
    Disagree,
    Maybe,
    DoNotKnow
};

public Decisions CurrentDecision
{
    get {}
    set {}
}

public RelayCommand ToggleDecisionStateCommand
{
       // In here, call code to execute toggle
       if (mCurrentDecision == Decisions.DoNotKnow)
           CurrentDecision = Decisions.Agree;
       else
           CurrentDecision += 1;       
}

public ImageSource CurrentDecisionIcon
{
    get
    {
        ImageSource img = [some default image];
        switch (mCurrentDecision)
        {
            case Decisions.Agree:
                img = [path to Agree icon];
                break;

            // Other cases here
        }

        return img;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use 3-state check box, you must change the behind boolean value(in ViewModel)
to bool? type.

```
  public bool? IsEnabled { get; set; }
```

and Set this property for CheckBox

```
  IsThreeState = True;
```

Comment: I have to show change the Icon for 4 diferent states Agree,Disagree,Maybe,I Dont care.....